# How to concat int and char* and return char* in Win32 c++ Dll?

Tags: c++, dll

I have written a win32 DLL by using visual studio 2012.

My function return type is char*:

```
extern "C" TESTDLL_API char* SelectColor()
{

}
```

I want to return string in my main application (C#):

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
[DllImport("TESTDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern string SelectColor();
```

in body of the SelectColor method I must to concat some char* and int.
I tested this codes until now:

```
char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
char* result = new char[1000];
sprintf(result,"%s%s", result ,cid0);
sprintf(result,"%s%s", result ,cid1);
return result;
```

This returns wrong string;

```
char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
char * result = (char*)calloc(strlen(cid0) + strlen(cid1) + 1, sizeof(char));
strcat(result, cid0);
strcat(result, cid1);
return result;
```

This will fail;

```
char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
stringstream ss;
ss << cid0 << cid1 << number;
return (char*)ss.str().c_str();
```

This returns empty string;

What I must do?
Sorry for bad english.
Thanks.

Comment: If you are programming for the Win32 API, I recommend to use strsafe.h functions such as StringCbCat, StringCchCat, etc. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647466(v=vs.85).aspx

What is the code of GetCPUID?

Comment: *My function return type is char*:*  -- That right there is an issue.  Instead, let the caller pass you a buffer, and you fill it in with the data.  If you want a point of reference, how many Windows API functions return `char *`?  I bet few, if any do that.

Comment: unfortunately, I have to return string, and can't change return type!. the GetCPUID is a function that returns char*. I am programming in .Net 2 and c# language.

Comment: @Ali.M Return back the pointer to the buffer that the user passed to you.  The bottom line is to let the caller be responsible for giving you a buffer, instead of your code allocating and causing memory leaks.  You can return the pointer they passed to you because it is a pointer to the buffer the client set up themselves.  But on a bigger note, if it were so sound to return char*, then why no Windows API functions do it?  Instead you see the API functions do similar to what I stated (or do what the answer from milevyo is suggesting).

Comment: @Ali.M And your last attempt in your question fails due to returning a pointer to a local variable.  So instead of fighting with potential memory leaks (who will be responsible for that memory to be deallocated?), and returning pointers to local variables, you can eliminate the entire issue by having the user pass you a buffer and a size.  Then no headaches for you -- all you do is fill the buffer (respecting the size given), and return the pointer back.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am developing only the dll. Unfortunately I can't force the user to pass parameter to the function. I have to modify body of this function!!

Comment: That's a very poorly designed public API. As PaulMcKenzie already said, you cannot return a pointer to a local variable and it's always better to have the caller allocate memory because the caller knows when to free it.

Answer (score 2):

i guess by :

```
char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
char* result = new char[1000];
sprintf(result,"%s%s", result ,cid0);
sprintf(result,"%s%s", result ,cid1);
return result;
```

you want to do this;

```
char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
char* result = new char[1000];
sprintf(result,"%s%s", cid0,cid1);
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't change main method prototype. the function have not any parameter and must returns string!

Comment: @Ali.M The answer given is the defacto way to do this.  What you're after is hardly ever done, unless you manage all the string allocation and deallocation in some methodical way (provide another DLL function to deallocate the memory, etc.).  As my other comment suggested, returning a pointer to a local variable is not an option, regardless of your requirements.

Comment: Can the function returns type other than char* and get string in main application?

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely cannot change the signature of the function, then you will have to return a pointer to a static memory buffer to ensure the pointer is not leaked (in the case of your `new[]` and `calloc()` examples) or freed prematurely (in the case of your `stringstream` example), eg:

```
char result[1000];

extern "C" TESTDLL_API char* SelectColor()
{
    char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
    char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
    StringCchPrintfA(result, 1000, "%s%s", cid0, cid1);
    return result;
}
```

Or:

```
std::string result;

extern "C" TESTDLL_API char* SelectColor()
{
    char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
    char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << cid0 << cid1;
    result = oss.str();
    return result.c_str();
}
```

Note that this is not thread-safe.  If multiple threads need to call the function at the same time, use a memory buffer in thread-local storage, eg:

```
__declspec(thread) char result[1000];

extern "C" TESTDLL_API char* SelectColor()
{
    char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
    char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
    StringCchPrintfA(result, 1000, "%s%s", cid0, cid1);
    return result;
}
```

**Update**: If the content of the buffer never changes, you can initialize the buffer once and just keep returning it as-is:

```
struct sResult
{
    char buffer[1000];

    sResult()
    {
        char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
        char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
        StringCchPrintfA(buffer, 1000, "%s%s", cid0, cid1);
    }
};

extern "C" TESTDLL_API char* SelectColor()
{
    static sResult result;
    return result.buffer;
}
```

Or:

```
static char result[1000];

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        char* cid0 = GetCpuID(0);
        char* cid1 = GetCpuID(1);
        StringCchPrintfA(buffer, 1000, "%s%s", cid0, cid1);
    }
    return TRUE;
};

extern "C" TESTDLL_API char* SelectColor()
{
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you are putting `result` variable in global scope. I understand that, because GetCpuID(0) && GetCpuID(0) never change. what about putting it in static scope so that GetCpuID() will be called only once?. anyway, i vote up.

Comment: You are assuming the value of `GetCpuID()` never changes. We don't know what `GetCpuID()` actually does.  In any case, the point of this exercise is to make sure the returned pointer is pointing at persistent memory, the content of the memory is not relevant.

Comment: IMHO if result of GetCpuID()  may change, then i think it is bad idea to return a global or a static variable , think about multiple calls from the same thread not even from multi-thread.

Comment: In the first examples I provided, the value of `GetCpuID()` is allowed to change between calls. What is important is the buffer that the values are copied into, not the values themselves.  The buffer needs to remain allocated after the function exits. .NET will not free the pointer that is returned, the DLL needs to keep it allocated in a manner that will not leak.